# How to stop python pandas from adding "00:00:00" to every date?

Tags: python, pandas

Writing time series data to a `csv` file using `pandas.Series.to_csv` adds `00:00:00` to every date index which is annoying when the csv file is opened in another application.

```
Date,price
2000-06-01 00:00:00,90.3
2000-06-02 00:00:00,92.69
2000-06-05 00:00:00,96.1
```

Is there a clean/pythonic way to write date values as just dates without the extra `00:00:00`?

And more generally is it possible with `pandas` to have an index column which is date as opposed to time-stamp?

**Edit:** for those who may visit this question this is the solution I came up with:

```
with io.StringIO() as sout:
  data.to_csv(sout, header=True, index=True)
  with open(fname, 'w') as fout:
    fout.write(sout.getvalue().replace(' 00:00:00',''))
```

Comment: What type are you using when you create the Series? `datetime.datetime` or `datetime.date`?

Comment: @Collin I read the series from csvfile, `pd.read_csv(path, index_col=0, parse_dates=True)`

Comment: Never done this, so I'm not sure I'm comfortable answering, but [read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.9.1/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html?highlight=csv#pandas.io.parsers.read_csv) includes a way to pass in a custom `date_parser` function, whouch you could provide that returns a `date` rather than a `datetime`.

Comment: @Collin it ends up spitting out a string, so you should be able to just write a lambda that calls `date.strftime(format)` with the required format.

Comment: this will be setup in 0.12, see https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2583

Answer (score 2):

Map your Series/Dataframe before writing to the csv file:

```
In [8]: import pandas as pd

In [9]: import datetime

In [10]: s = pd.Series([datetime.datetime.utcnow()])

In [11]: s.map(lambda x:x.date() if isinstance(x, datetime.datetime) else x).to_csv('test.csv')
```

test.csv:

```
0,2013-03-27
```

Comment: this does not work for the index column and for a `DataFrame`

Answer (score 2):

With the new version of Pandas you can use the date_format parameter of the [to_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) method:

```
df.to_csv(filename, date_format='%Y%m%d')
```